# Good resource on how to write dot net unit test cases?

Tags: unit-tests, coverage, dot-net

I am looking for good resources on how to write good unit test cases in C#/Dot Net. Books, resources on the net or simply good advises. In particular the unit cases should give good code coverage and cover all functionality.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried the book The Art of Unit Testing ?
http://www.manning.com/osherove/

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend the book "Pragmatic Unit Testing in C# with NUnit" by Andrew Hunt and David Thomas.

If you are using Visual Studio as your IDE you might also want to check out MSDN  (e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182532.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

General Rules:

- At least one test method should be written for every public service method and every new or overridden repository method
- Where applicable, positive and negative tests should be written
- Every Assert should include a relevant, meaningful error message for when failure occurs
- The Arrange, Act, Assert pattern should always be followed (see below)
- Read this article on MSDN:  [Guidelines forTest-Driven Development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa730844).

Arrange, Act, Assert:

Follow the "3-As" pattern for test methods: (Arrange, Act, Assert). Specifically, use separate code paragraphs (groups of lines of code separated by a blank line) for each of the As.

- Arrange is variable declaration and initialization.
- Act is invoking the code under test.
- Assert is using the Assert.* methods to verify that expectations were met. Following this pattern consistently makes it easy to revisit test code.

This makes it much easier to see:

- What is being set up and initialized in the arrange section
- What method is being executed in the act section
- What determines the outcome of the test in the assert section

See the following post for more details
http://tekprolixity.blogspot.com/2012/04/unit-testing-guidelines.html

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest look into this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms379625%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) link. But you can bing "unit test using VSTS" and you will get tons of help.